# $.ajax - POST ..... 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou enviando uma requisição a uma URL pela função `$.ajax()` e preciso que me retorne um dos parametros (**foi, error, nothing**). No *localhost* está funcionando corretamente, coloquei no servidor e retorna **POST http://www.clickbankonline.com.br/backoffice/insertFila 500 (Internal Server Error)**.

Eu clico em um botão e faz a requisição JS nesse código:

```
$.ajax({
                url: baseURL+'backoffice/insertFila', 
                data: {bandeira:bandeira,conta:conta,agencia:agencia,tipo:tipo,titular:titular,cpf:cpf,skf:skf},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(callback){


                    if(callback == 'nothing'){

                        $("#retorno").html('<div class="alert alert-info" align="center"><b>Atenção:</b> Não existe nenhum usuário na fila que você escolheu, por favor, tente mudar a bandeira ou a fila para se cadastrar e entrar em uma fila.</div>');
                        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, '2000');

                    }else{

                        if(callback == 'foi'){

                        $("#btn-cadastroFila").prop('disabled', true);
                        $("#retorno").html('<div class="alert alert-success" align="center">Você foi cadastrado na fila, aguarde enquanto redirecionamos você.</div>');
                        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, '2000');

                        }else{

                        $("#retorno").html('<div class="alert alert-info" align="center"><b>Alerta:</b> Não foi possível cadastrar sua conta em nossa fila. Entre em contato com nosso suporte para resolvermos seu problema.<br />Erro: '+callback+'</div>');
                        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, '2000');

                        }

                    }
                }

            });
```

E chama a URL **http://www.clickbankonline.com.br/backoffice/insertFila** que contém o código:

```
public function insertFila(){

        $bandeira = $this->input->post('bandeira');
        $conta = $this->input->post('conta');
        $agencia = $this->input->post('agencia');
        $tipo = $this->input->post('tipo');
        $titular = $this->input->post('titular');
        $cpf = $this->input->post('cpf');
        $skf = $this->input->post('skf'); //IDFila

        $this->db->where('id_usuario', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
        $this->db->where('fila', $skf);
        $this->db->where('liberado', 1);
        $this->db->where('usado', 0);
        $this->db->where('retroalimentacao', 1);
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');

        $retroalimentacao = $this->db->get('sistema');

        if($retroalimentacao->num_rows() <= 0){

            $userID = $this->session->userdata('user_id');


            $queryCheck = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM fila WHERE id_fila = '$skf' AND id_bandeira = '$bandeira' AND liberado = '1' AND doacoes < '2' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");

            if($queryCheck->num_rows() > 0){

            $rowReceptor = $queryCheck->row();

            $Doacoes = $rowReceptor->doacoes+1;
            $IDReceptorFila = $rowReceptor->id;
            $IDReceptor = $rowReceptor->id_usuario;

            $this->db->where('id', $IDReceptorFila);
            $Refresh = $this->db->update('fila', array('doacoes'=>$Doacoes));

                if($Refresh){

                    $this->db->where('id_indicado', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
                    $dataReferencia = $this->db->get('referencia');

                    if($dataReferencia->num_rows() > 0){

                        $this->db->where('id_indicado', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
                        $this->db->where('doacao', '0');

                        $this->db->update('referencia', array('doacao'=>'1'));
                    }

                    $isFila = $this->db->insert('fila', array('id_usuario'=>$userID, 'id_bandeira'=>$bandeira, 'id_fila'=>$skf, 'agencia'=>$agencia, 'conta'=>$conta,'tipo'=>$tipo,'titular'=>$titular,'cpf'=>$cpf, 'liberado'=>'0', 'doacoes'=>'0'));
                    $IDFilaInsert = $this->db->insert_id();

                    $Insert = $this->db->insert('pendentes', array('id_doador'=>$userID, 'id_receptor'=>$IDReceptor, 'id_fila'=>$IDFilaInsert, 'id_fila_receptor'=>$IDReceptorFila, 'pago'=>'0', 'tempo'=>(time() + 1800)));

                    $this->db->where('id_usuario', $userID);
                    $this->db->update('sistema', array('usado'=>1));

                    $this->db->where('id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
                    $cadastroCheck = $this->db->get('cadastros');

                    //enviarSMS('Voce acabou de se cadastrar na fila da ClickBank, agora va ate o menu Doacoes Pendentes e faca sua doacao', $cadastroCheck->row()->celular, $cadastroCheck->row()->mensagem);

                    if($Insert && $isFila){

                        echo 'foi';
                    }else{
                        echo 'error';
                    }
                }

            }else{

                echo 'nothing';
            }

        }else{

            //Caso for de retroalimentação

            $userID = $this->session->userdata('user_id');


            $queryCheck = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM fila WHERE id_fila = '1' AND id_bandeira = '$bandeira' AND liberado = '1' AND doacoes < '2' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");

            if($queryCheck->num_rows() > 0){

            $rowReceptor = $queryCheck->row();

            $Doacoes = $rowReceptor->doacoes+1;
            $IDReceptorFila = $rowReceptor->id;
            $IDReceptor = $rowReceptor->id_usuario;

            $this->db->where('id', $IDReceptorFila);
            $Refresh = $this->db->update('fila', array('doacoes'=>$Doacoes));

                if($Refresh){

                    $isFila = $this->db->insert('fila', array('id_usuario'=>$userID, 'id_bandeira'=>$bandeira, 'id_fila'=>$skf, 'agencia'=>$agencia, 'conta'=>$conta,'tipo'=>$tipo,'titular'=>$titular,'cpf'=>$cpf, 'liberado'=>'0', 'doacoes'=>'0'));
                    $IDFilaInsert = $this->db->insert_id();

                    $Insert = $this->db->insert('pendentes', array('id_doador'=>$userID, 'id_receptor'=>$IDReceptor, 'id_fila'=>$IDFilaInsert, 'id_fila_receptor'=>$IDReceptorFila, 'pago'=>'0', 'tempo'=>(time() + 1800), 'retroalimentacao'=>1));

                    $this->db->where('id_usuario', $userID);
                    $this->db->update('sistema', array('usado'=>1));

                    $this->db->where('id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
                    $cadastroCheck = $this->db->get('cadastros');


                    if($Insert && $isFila){

                        echo 'foi';
                    }else{
                        echo 'error';
                    }
                }

            }else{

                echo 'nothing';
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Você pode olhar no console do navegador (f12 - Chrome) va até a aba network, procure e clique na página onde ocorreu o Internal Server Error e veja qual foi o erro exatamente...

Comment: Erro 500 é do servidor veja ou habilite as mensagens de erro do php.

Comment: No PHP não está com erro, tanto que executei o link normalmente.

Comment: Remote Address:198.24.156.58:80
Request URL:http://www.clickbankonline.com.br/backoffice/insertFila
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

bandeira:8
conta:53367
agencia:---
tipo:Conta Pré-pago
titular:123
cpf:31
skf:1

Connection:close
Content-Length:477
Content-Type:text/html

@RafaelWithoeft

Comment: @AlissonAcioli Você executou o "ajax" e deixou a aba network aberta? Ao ser executado o ajax vai aparecer pra você na aba network... após clicar no link que deu o internal server error... **na outra aba preview** dentro do link, você pode ver o stack trace do erro; Não mostrou nenhum erro ai?

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft dentro da aba network->Preview aparece apenas uma página de erro **HTTP 500**

Comment: Então não tem erro de código. Caso fosse poderia aparecer algo como: PHP Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: return123'

Comment: O problema é que localmente ele funciona normalmente

Comment: @AlissonAcioli já olhou os logs do apache?

Comment: A versão do php é a mesma nos dois servidores? o `ini_set('display_errors', true)` e o `error_reporting(E_ALL)` você colocou na pagina que fica em branco.

Comment: @rray arrumei, o problema era o nome de uma tabela que estava errada. Obrigado!

Comment: @AlissonAcioli Se possível poste uma resposta explicando como você resolveu o problema e depois marque-a como aceita. :)

Comment: O erro era o nome da tabela que estava errada no SELECT e me retornava os erros acima.